# Will not shut down

Tags: dell, power-management, shutdown

My Dell Inspiron 1720 Laptop with 12.04 with latest updates will not shut down when commanded off.

After each upgrade it will probably turn off once, the next time it is commanded off, it will shut down to the numlock, power and bluetooth lights. Holding power switch for 5 seconds completes the turnoff. Tried the terminal command `sudo shutdown -h now` with no different result.

Changing the video driver from NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (version 173-updates) to NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (version current-updates) also gave me a single command shutdown but no more.

Answer (score 1):

shutdown -h states:

"Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the system."

in other words, the behaviour is platform specific, some hardware will halt the machine (and not power it off), other hardware will also power it off.  Perhaps you need to use "sudo shutdown -P now" instead.

See also: http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/semantics-of-halt.html